# Passing same value to multiple tasks in locust

Tags: locust

We have a requirement where we need to send a post request and then send a delete request for the same end point(REST API).

Need to generate a unique id for each post request, for each user in each iteration.
generated unique string is put inside on_start() method of task class (SequentialTaskSet).

Problem is, it runs for one iteration, but generates same id for consecutive iterations for each user.
To get unique id for each user in each iteration, generating the unique string within the task itself works, but issue here is, I could not pass the same Id to next task where I need to send delete request.

This is what code looks like now:

```
class StudentClass(SequentialTaskSet):

    rndString = None

    def on_start(self):
        self.rndString = str(uuid.uuid4())

    @task
    def postRequest(self):

        endpoint = "/students"

        headers = {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer token',
            'content-type': 'application/json', 'accept': 'application/json'
        }

        data = {
            "Id": f'std-{self.rndString}',
        }

        with self.client.post(endpoint, name="Post request", headers=headers, data=json.dumps(data),
                              catch_response=True) as response:
        ........
```

Appreciate any help in achieving this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think if you don't need to call post and delete requests with different weights you can do both calls in same task. Is there something I am missing that requires you to separate tasks for post and delete calls? If yo do need to separate them you can update the `self.rndString` in post task and it will use the updated one in delete.

Comment: Thank you for the response Muhammed Tanır. Yeah, in that case we could have used within the same task, but we need to measure two different requests separately for POST and DELETE, hence need two different tasks.

Comment: As far as I know locust logs each call separately regardless of the task they are in , request_success and request_failure events trigger for each call. Hope that helps.

Comment: oh ok.. I did'nt know that.. Will check and If that gives separate transactions, then the problem is solved. But again, we should have different variable names for data, headers etc. and all in the task method. Not an issue though. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
@task(1)
def hello_world(self):
    response = self.client.get("/listing")
    print(response.text)

@task
def fill_crud(self):
    response = self.client.post('/api/fill_post/', {"number_1": 76, "number_2": 897, "number_3": 564, "text_4": "Sneha"})
    print(response.status_code)
    res = json.loads(response.text)
    response_id = (res['id'])
    response_put = self.client.put(f'/api/fill_post/{response_id}/', {"number_1": 76576, "number_2": 89657, "number_3": 5654, "text_4": "Sneha"})
    response_patch = self.client.patch(f'/api/fill_post/{response_id}/', {"text_4": "Suveksha"})
    response_delete = self.client.delete(f'/api/fill_post/{response_id}/')
```

You can try it in this way, I hope it will helps anyone.